# how to specify previous version of source file in PCL-CVS?

Tags: emacs, cvs

In PCL-CVS documentation, following section describes how to see CVS differentce. It also talks about giving prefix argument to specify previous revision. But I am not able understand what prefix argument should be given for previous revision.

> **d e**
>
> This uses ediff (or emerge, depending on ‘cvs-idiff-imerge-handlers’)
>   to allow you to view diffs. If a prefix argument is given, PCL-CVS
>   will prompt for a revision against which the diff should be made, else
>   the default will be to use the BASE revision.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, prefix arguments in Emacs are given by [prefixing a command with `C-u` followed by an optional argument](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Prefix-Command-Arguments.html).

In this case, it doesn't sounds like it matters what the argument is, so `C-u d e` should cause Emacs to prompt you for a revision.